# W-4 filled out, no taxes take out of paycheck?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

I filled out a w4 upon hire and employer never took taxes out of my check. Is it legal for them to have a w4 on file and not take taxes out your paycheck?

---

ETA: Exempt was not specified on the W-4 and no taxes were taken out of the paychecks at all.

Comment: Can you clarify what they did or did not take out? Also, how did you fill out your W-4? One of the possible options is to not withhold any taxes, which for some situations makes sense. Regardless, you’re still responsible for paying taxes you owe regardless how much or little you’re employer withholds.

Answer (score 3):

If you filled out the form, did not specify "Exempt" below 4(c), and did not specify high enough deductions that you would have nothing withheld, then the employer should follow the rules, withhold a specific amount of money, and pay it to the government, as reported on your W-2. If an employer willfully fails to withhold and pay the required taxes, they are liable for criminal and civil sanctions. [This page](https://www.irs.gov/compliance/criminal-investigation/employer-and-employee-responsibilities-employment-tax-enforcement) from the IRS provides a phone number to complain about an employer not correctly withholding federal income and employment taxes.

Comment: Of course, if the wages are very low, the required amount of withholding could be zero, even if the employee is not exempt or has no allowances.